# Change the fields and tables which are accessed in a query from within the body of a CASE expression [Oracle SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle

Im attempting to change the fields and tables which are accessed in a query from within the body of a CASE expression:

```
PACOTE AS (SELECT *
             FROM (SELECT CASE 
                            WHEN OE.CUST_STAT_CD = 'Prospect'
                              THEN (TB1.COLUMNONE, TB2.COLUMNTWO
                                    FROM TABLEONE TB1, 
                                         TABLEONE TB2)
                            ELSE (L.COLUMNONE, I.COLUMNTWO
                                  FROM TABLELOREM L, 
                                       TABLEIPSUM I)
                          END
                   )
          )
```

Comment: Is `PACOTE` intended to be a common table expression?

Comment: Yes! It is intended to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is to change the fields and tables which are accessed in a query from within the body of a CASE expression. I've reformatted your code to make this clear:

```
PACOTE AS (SELECT *
             FROM (SELECT CASE 
                            WHEN OE.CUST_STAT_CD = 'Prospect'
                              THEN (TB1.COLUMNONE, TB2.COLUMNTWO
                                    FROM TABLEONE TB1, 
                                         TABLEONE TB2)
                            ELSE (L.COLUMNONE, I.COLUMNTWO
                                  FROM TABLELOREM L, 
                                       TABLEIPSUM I)
                          END
                   )
          )
```

Sorry, but this is simply not allowed in SQL. Also, you've got a table alias `OE` which is used in your CASE expression but isn't defined elsewhere so it's difficult to advise you on what to do. Generally, however, you'll need to use a UNION, similar to

```
SELECT tb1.COLUMN1, tb2.COLUMN2
  FROM TABLEONE tb1,
       TABLETWO tb2
  WHERE oe.CUST_STAT_CD = 'Prospect'
UNION ALL
SELECT l.COLUMNONE, i.COLUMNTWO
  FROM TABLELOREM l,
       TABLEIPSUM i
  WHERE oe.CUST_STAT_CODE <> 'Prospect'
```

Comment: I will try that! Give me a minute

Comment: THIS IS IT! Thank you so much! And sorry for not giving enough information on my question, I will improve it!

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid SQL:

```
PACOTE AS (  
 CASE
```

You probably intend:

```
PACOTE AS (  
 SELECT CASE
```

Comment: I tried to change the query as you say, but not i have a new error